# How to recall the results of if-else in the definition of a new function

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I'm new to Python and although I'm reading as much as I can on Stackoverflow and manuals, I can't find a solution to what is maybe a little problem.

I have defined a function with if-else, giving different result for each condition. Now I want to define a new function, again with if-else, where I can reuse those different results as conditions in the new function.

I thought that assigning each result of Function1 to local variables would make it easier to recall each results for each of the later if-else conditions, but it seems there's something wrong in what I'm doing. Here's the thing.

```
def Function1(self, some_value):
    if some_value == self.__dict__:                     
      return self.name, some_value
    else:
         return obj.name, attr, some_value

#obj is some obj taken from a dict somewhere else

   first_condition = return self.name, some_value
   second_condition= return obj.name, attr, some_value

def Function2(self):
    if Function1.first_condition:
      print(self.name)
    elif Function1.second_condition:
      print(self.name, object.name)
    else:
        print('failed')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the results of a function, you have to call it first. So, in `Function2` you should first call `Function1` and then simply check the number of results it returns (the number of values in the tuple returned):

```
def Function2(self):
    k=len(Function1(self, "test"))
    if k==2: print(self.name)
    elif k==3: print("anything")
    else: printf("failed")
```

You should definitely remove `first_condition` and `second_condition`.

If these functions are a part of a class, you can create a variable, called, eg. `self.res` and store needed data there.

```
def Function1(self, some_value):
    if ...:
        #do something
        self.res=1
        #return something
    else:
        #do something
        self.res=2
        #return something
```

And then in `Function2` you just check the `self.res` variable.

Comment: In Function1 I basically need to have an assignment as result of each condition. So, "if ... : x = a, b, c; else: y = e, f, g". I would then use x and y as conditions in Function2. Like "if x-conditionOccurs: do-this; elif y-conditionOccurs: do-that; else: 'failed' ". I have the feeling there's someting conceptually wrong in the way I'm trying to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Consider what is meant by these two "phrases" (taken out of context)

Function1.first_condition:
Function1.second_condition:

The form of these two phrases suggests a state, a value (probably an integer) which indicates which of these two (first_condition or second_condition) applies.

There can be many solutions to your inquiry. A slightly oversimplified version is to suggest an integer you've not yet declared could be used to remember which of the two conditions was chosen inside Function1. The function itself could return a 1 or 2 depending on which decision was made, giving you a simple "if decision == 1:" means of responding.

I say this is slightly oversimplified, but it is often used. In this context you may be saying that of the two possible decisions, the result is a different "type" of return. Types are more important in some languages than others, but types can be used to determine a course of action just as integers might be used, and it is a more advanced concept in choosing behavior based on some decision. If your use of python is in an early phase, you may well choose to use the integer approach as a means of determining what decision was taken.

Comment: Thanks both for replying. I was trying to follows your suggestions, but I don't seem to make it right. In Function2, what I want to mean is "if firstConditionInFunction1Occurs: do this; elif secondConditionInFunction1Occurs: do smthElse; else: failed". The closest thing to this seemed to be "if decision == 1". But I don't get how I should implement it from Function1 to Function2.